# How to fix xmlMapper "Multiple fields representing property "PS"" issue with Jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb, xmlmapper

I used Jaxb to generate a Jar file from xsd:

```
CustomObject inputRequest = xmlMapper.readValue(input, CustomObject.class);
```

The error message I am getting is:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple fields
>   representing property "PS": OrderLineType#pS vs OrderLineType#pSV5 at
>   [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]

And my class is:

```
@XmlElement(name = "PS", namespace = "financetypes:defn:v4")
protected financetypes.v4.PSType pS;
@XmlElement(name = "PS", namespace = "financetypes:defn:v5")
protected financetypes.v5.PSType pSV5;
```

They have the same name, but different namespace.

Is xmlmapper able to handle XmlElement that has the same name and different namespace?

If yes, how do I fix this? If no, what should I do?

I am building jar file from jenkin. Is there a plugin that I can use to fix this issue?

Thanks!

here is my xsd
v4.xsd

```
    <!--Begin Definition: Complex Type: PriceStructureType-->
<xs:complexType name="PriceStructureType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="PriceModel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Will be required in future...
                    TODO: Add valid items...
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="finance:SourceSystemPrice" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Will be required in future...
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ComponentPrice" type="finance:ComponentListType" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Will be required in future...
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="PriceStructure" type="finance:PriceStructureType"/>
<!--End Definition: Complex Type: PriceStructureType-->
```

v5.xsd

```
    <!--Begin Definition: Complex Type: PriceStructureType-->
<xs:complexType name="PriceStructureType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="PriceModel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Will be required in future...
                    TODO: Add valid items...
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="finance:SourceSystemPrice" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Will be required in future...
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ComponentPrice" type="finance:ComponentListType" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Will be required in future...
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="PriceStructure" type="finance:PriceStructureType"/>
<!--End Definition: Complex Type: PriceStructureType-->
```

common.xsd

```
xmlns:finance="urn:financetypes:defn:v4"
xmlns:finance_v5="urn:financetypes:defn:v5"
<xs:import namespace="urn:financetypes:defn:v4" schemaLocation="financetypes.v4.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="urn:financetypes:defn:v5" schemaLocation="financetypes.v5.xsd"/>

<xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="finance:PriceStructure" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Price Structure itemizes the price components of this OrderLine.  Pricing
                        is a integral part of the Sales Order record.
                        This should be a required element for a sales order, but it is marked
                        as optional for backward compatibility. 
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="finance_v5:PriceStructure" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Price Structure itemizes the price components of this OrderLine.  Pricing
                        is a integral part of the Sales Order record.
                        This should be a required element for a sales order, but it is marked
                        as optional for backward compatibility. 
                    </xs:documentation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:property name="PriceStructureV5"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this. For a root class containing these 2 elements:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "PS", namespace = "financetypes:defn:v4")
    protected financetypes.v4.PSType pS;
    @XmlElement(name = "PS", namespace = "financetypes:defn:v5")
    protected financetypes.v5.PSType pSV5;
}
```

You can create you classes with the different versions like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "v4PS", namespace = "financetypes:defn:v4")
public class PSType {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;
}
```

and:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "v5PS", namespace = "financetypes:defn:v5")
public class PSType {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;
}
```

For a sample xml as below:

```
<root xmlns:v4="financetypes:defn:v4" xmlns:v5="financetypes:defn:v5">
    <v4:PS>version 4</v4:PS>
    <v5:PS>version 5</v5:PS>
</root>
```

You will be able to unmarshall properly.

Update to respond to the comment:

You use xsd to generate the classes. You did not provide the xsd so I will assume you are not allowed to. I created an xsd to generate the classes you show in your question. The namespace.xsd looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:v4="financetypes:defn:v4" xmlns:v5="financetypes:defn:v5">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="v4PSType" type="PSTypev4" />
                <xs:element name="v5PSType" type="PSTypev5" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="PSTypev4">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string" />
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="PSTypev5">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Then your bindings would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/namespaces.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='PSTypev4']">
            <annox:annotate target = "class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType" name="v4PSType" namespace="financetypes:defn:v4" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>

        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='PSTypev5']">
            <annox:annotate target = "class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType" name="v5PSType" namespace="financetypes:defn:v5" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>

        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='root']//xs:complexType//xs:all//xs:element[@name='v5PSType']">
            <annox:annotate target = "field">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement" name="PS" namespace="financetypes:defn:v5" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>

        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='root']//xs:complexType//xs:all//xs:element[@name='v4PSType']">
            <annox:annotate target = "field">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement" name="PS" namespace="financetypes:defn:v4" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And then you would end up with classes as those in my answer.

Comment: Class is generated by jenkin.  How do I modify then during building stage?

Comment: @Aodirary How? Do you have some xsds and you run a maven plugin to generate the classes in your Jenkins job?

Comment: Yes.  I have some xsds that is stastic and I run a maven plugin to generate the classes in build.gradle

Comment: @Aodirary you can use bindings to add the annotation then. Can you paste me a sample of your xsd?

Comment: How do I use bindings to add the annotation?

Comment: @Aodirary I will update in the answer to show you how

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps a lot. yeah, i just created a binding xjb file. and add plugins to gradle.

Comment: @Aodirary happy to help

Comment: Hello, question about schemaLocation, actually, that was generated by two several xsd.  there are financetypev4.xsd and financetypev5.xsd.  Both are needed.  what should I do with it?

Comment: @Aodirary in the bindings you want to reach some nodes to add your annotations. You would then have bindings per xsd. What references v4 to the v4 xsd schema location and the same for v5

Comment: I am getting XPath evaluation of "//xs:complexType[@name='v4PSType']" results in empty target node..

Comment: @Aodirary yes because this uses the nodes of the xsd I created. Cannot have the proper path without seeing your xsd. See what is the path and node names of the one you target and adjust in bindings

Comment: Oh. I post the xsd files on original questions text.  Can you take a look? thanks

Comment: @Aodirary ok I m bit busy now. will be back in couple pf hours amd take a look

Comment: @Aodirary you did not provide all xsds necessary to generate your classes. As far as I understand these xsds are the ones describing PSType class. There is another xsd that uses them as elements? Can you provide it?

Comment: Yes. I also add them to the question.

Comment: @Aodirary The xsd you post do not seem valid to me, I think you remove info from what you have. I cannot generate the classes. But you should be able to understand the idea behind it from the example I gave you. You want bindings for generating annotation under certain classes. For example to reach finance:PriceStructure you go choice -> element PriceStructure. I believe in your xsd you have something prior to choice. See my example, run it, try to understand how it works and then adapt for your xsds

Comment: Hey, I think you can help me with that.  Actually, I don't really need That field.  If I do @JsonIgnoreProperties("PriceStructure") in the class I built.  xmlmapper will go through.  How do I ignore those properties without touching jar file?

Comment: Or anyway to ignore PriceStructure in the binding?

Comment: @Aodirary If I understand you correctly, the annotation you look for I think is `@XmlTransient`. This brings us to the same issue however. You have xsds for generating the classes and you need to get to the same node in your bindings to "decorate" it with `@XmlTransient`.

Comment: I added @ignore on the @XmlElement(name = "PS", namespace = "financetypes:defn:v4") and class.  Then the issue is gone.  Because I need to use the jar file later.  I want to know how to make that happen in binding.

Comment: @Aodirary ok, then what is your goal? how to add this annotation using bindings?

Comment: Yes.  Add annotation by using the binding. is that possible?  and import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.Jsonignore

Comment: @Aodirary it might, but I am not sure how. Please try to use `@XmlTransient` and let me know if it works. The this, we can do via bindings.

Comment: Hey, I have add annotate @XmlTransient to the element, and it works .@XmlTransient
    @XmlElement(name = "PriceStructure", namespace = "xxxxxxx.v4")